# firefox 11 and richfaces 3.1.5.GA/jsf 1.1.11 html injection

Tags: firefox, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf, myfaces

So we have a jsf/myfaces + rf app that works fine with FF 10.  But FF 11 came out this week and we saw an issue with html injection from a4j tags.  If we have a simple facelet page, and add just a single a4j component, firefox 11 will render TWO head and body tags (one pair of head and body tags are just empty - and they are rendered in somewhat random order, sometimes the empty body tag is after our page content, sometimes before).
This throws off a lot of our complex css and jquery logic on the client side (we have a css/js developer who is playing around with some hacky ways around it but that's not ideal).  Are other people seeing this or have any idea of a workaround so a4j tags do not auto-inject extra head/body tags?

I've heard that jsf2/richfaces 4 does not have this issue but upgrading would take a lot of time and effort at this point so wanted to see if there were any other options (and I guess also to confirm it is indeed the case that rf4 doesn't have this issue with FF 11 if we do have to end up upgrading).  Thanks.

Comment: I'd report it to the RichFaces guys.

Comment: Can someone recommend the patch required for: /org/ajax4jsf/javascript/scripts/AJAX.js ??

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a FF bug: Ajax-Response is okay but after html injection the resource key of a a4j:mediaOutput is modified (looks like it is URL-Encoded). So the resource lookup fails.
After pressing F5 the whole page is requested and the urls are valid.
I'm trying to say: I think your code is ok and we all have to wait for FF12.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FF started to support the "outerHtml" DOM property, so the "A4J.AJAX._scriptEvaluated" code is inserted using the fallback IE-targetting code instead of the code targetting modern browsers.

Jean Blanchard explains how to fix it  [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/724427?tstart=0).

> To fix it you would have to update the file /org/ajax4jsf/javascript/scripts/AJAX.js from richfaces-impl.jar.
>   Unfortunately, I don't have access to the library, so here is the ugly workaround I'm using :

```
      &lt;!--[if !IE]&gt; --&gt;
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        function fixA4J() {
            var bodies = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
            if (bodies.length > 1) {
               for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
                    if (bodies[i].firstChild == null) {
                        bodies[i].parentNode.removeChild(bodies[i])
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
                for (var i = 0; i < heads.length; i++) {
                    if (heads[i].children.length == 1) {
                        var s = heads[i].firstChild;
                        heads[i].parentNode.removeChild(heads[i])
                        document.head.appendChild(s);
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        window.setTimeout(fixA4J, 100);
    // ]]>
    </script>
    &lt;!-- &lt;![endif]--&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

We also had problems starting with FF11 and after trying a lot of stuff this thread solved all of our problems:

[FF11 and RichFaces](https://community.jboss.org/message/726437)